# Routing from aws ecs task to domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS fargate task that has a public IP and receives data from other devices.

However, each time the task restarts the public IP changes. I want to use a domain instead of the task IP.

How can I achieve this? I have tried adding task IP as target to loadbalancer and connect to the loadbalancer IP instead of task IP, this did not work.

Comment: "I have tried adding task IP as target to loadbalancer and connect to the loadbalancer IP instead of task IP, this did not work." You need to provide much more details about what you did here, and what specific issues you encountered.

Comment: thank you for your response. I guess the easiest way would be that you assume I did not try at all. What would be your suggested solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with the loadbalancer, since you can't set an static IP for ECS tasks [1]. You will need:

- Loadbalancer: Could be application or network loadbalancer, depends on your requirements. Type internal, if the task only receives internal traffic; internet-facing, for traffic from the internet. With its respective security group if it's an application loadbalancer.
- Target group: Type IP, where you register your ECS service.
- Listener: Attached to the loadbalancer, where the traffic comes in and where it goes (to which target group).
- (Optional) Domain: You can use the loadbalancer's DNS name, which looks like `<id>.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com`; or create your own of type CNAME (pointing to LB's DNS) or ALIAS (pointing to your LB, if you're using AWS Route53).

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-static-elastic-ip-address/

Comment: thank you for your response. If I click on create a target group there are 4 choices: instances, ip addresses, lambda function and application load balancer. One can not register an ECS service as a target group. How to proceed here?

Comment: @hurricane Create the target group with no targets, but when you create the ECS service you choose the previously created target group.

Comment: one can not create a target group without targets, one of the 4 choices must be chosen.

Comment: @hurricane type IP

Comment: "one can not create a target group without targets" is not correct. Did you follow the guide that was linked, step by step? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-static-elastic-ip-address/